# Align elements side-by-side with dynamic size

Tags: html, css

Here's the thing: I'm making a pure JavaScript full screen image slider, and I'm having a little trouble with my elements position.

The image's size needs to be dynamic, because it has to fit in every screen. I need all the elements aligned side-by-side, so I can animate the slider with a left/right effect.

Here's my issue: I can't get those elements aligned. They just stand vertically one below the other.

I really need those images with a 100% size, but that way I can't align them side-by-side. If i set a minor percentage (smaller then the parent size), or if I set a static value, they stand how I want.

What I need to do here?

You can find a live exemple here http://jsfiddle.net/9uF2b/

Here's some of my code:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="container" id="container">
            <ul>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="/teste/">
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="teste alt">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.slider {
width: 560px;
height: 560px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
// overflow: hidden;
}

img, a {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

li {
display: inline;
}

ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide!

Comment: please make a proper demo page here http://jsbin.com/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9uF2b/

Comment: try floating your li tags left, then set max-width and height for the images, and maybe fixed widths on the li tags.

Comment: @ChrisBrickhouse if I fix widths of li tags it works, but I need it full screen. I can't fix any width because the slide has to be full screen in any display, from the biggest to the smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `white-space: nowrap;` to your slider:

```
.slider {
    width: 560px;
    height: 560px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9uF2b/1/

Comment: yeaaaa boy! It worked! How does it works? I've never heard of it before.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` forces inline and inline-block elements to flow without wrapping. Read it [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are giving 100% height and width to img in in:
 `img, a {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}`

You have to give height and width 50% to img tag only as:

```
img{ width: 50%; height: 50%;}
```

So now images will add up to 100% width of parent cotainer. If you use more than 2 images then do the math accordingly.

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: yeah I said that on the question. If i set the width on a smaller percentage it works, but then it wont be full screen, know what I mean?

Comment: Are you using media queries at smaller screen resolutions?

Comment: No. Should I? My ideia is use big images (1800x1800 or larger) and then resize them to the screen resolution.